# Bold text on image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I want to append bold text on image, only selected text should be bold.

String word="This is dummy text, this should be **BOLD**"

```
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(Background));
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.drawString(word, curX, curY);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("output.bmp"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `AttributedString` and pass its `iterator` to `drawString`

```
static String Background = "input.png";
static int curX = 10;
static int curY = 50;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AttributedString word= new AttributedString("This is text. This should be BOLD");

    word.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    word.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLACK);

    // Sets the font to bold from index 29 (inclusive)
    // to index 33 (exclusive)
    word.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18), 29,33);
    word.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 29,33);

    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(Background));
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.drawString(word.getIterator(), curX, curY);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
}
```

output.png:

[image: This is text. This should be BOLD]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Font on the Graphics object before you draw the String like this:

`Font test = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);`

`g.setFont(test);`

If you only want one word bold you'll have to call drawString twice, and set the font to bold only the second time.

Comment: It will making all text to bold. I require only selected text should be bold

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help - curX,curY should be updated after the first drawString probably, otherwise it will look quite nasty. :)

```
String word="This is text, this should be ";
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(Background));
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.drawString(word, curX, curY);
Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.Bold, 72);
g.setFont(f);
String word="BOLD";
g.drawString(word, curX, curY);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("output.bmp"));
```